# How to find which variable is float64 when trying to use GPU in Theano

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

In theano, when using gpu, the variables have to be float32. I checked all my variables to be folat32, but I still get the error below.

```
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: local_gpu_incsubtensor
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/public/home/ybfan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/opt.py", line 1286, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
File "/public/home/ybfan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/opt.py", line 855, in local_gpu_incsubtensor
    gpu_from_host(y),
File "/public/home/ybfan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 399, in __call__
    node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
File "/public/home/ybfan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/basic_ops.py", line 128, in make_node
    dtype=x.dtype)()])
File "/public/home/ybfan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/type.py", line 68, in __init__
    (self.__class__.__name__, dtype, name))
TypeError: CudaNdarrayType only supports dtype float32 for now. Tried using dtype float64 for variable None
```

Seems that some variables are still float64, my question is how to locate the position I use the a float64 variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Theano 0.7, you can use the Theano flags: warn_float64. You can give him one of those values: 'ignore', 'warn', 'raise', 'pdb'.

This allow you to easily find where float64 are created.